# How to subclass list and trigger an event whenever the data change?

Tags: python

I would like to subclass `list` and trigger an event (data checking) every time any change happens to the data. Here is an example subclass:

```
class MyList(list):

   def __init__(self, sequence):
        super().__init__(sequence)
        self._test()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self._test()

    def append(self, value):
        super().append(value)
        self._test()

    def _test(self):
        """ Some kind of check on the data. """
        if not self == sorted(self):
            raise ValueError("List not sorted.")
```

Here, I am overriding methods `__init__`, `__setitem__` and `__append__` to perform the check if data changes. I think this approach is undesirable, so my question is: Is there a possibilty of triggering data checking automatically if *any* kind of mutation happens to the underlying data structure?

Comment: Do you care about mutable list entries? eg `m=MyList([[1],[2]]); m[0][0]=3` would not trigger `_test`. See the 3rd paragraph on [shelve.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#shelve.open) about that problem.

Comment: You could use [`sortedcontainers`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers/)`.SortedList` to get a list which will keep itself sorted

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus This is actually just a toy example. I don't really need to keep lists sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check-if-huge-list-in-python-has-changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871169/check-if-huge-list-in-python-has-changed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you say, this is not the best way to go about it. To correctly implement this, you'd need to know about every method that can change the list.

The way to go is to implement your own list (or rather a mutable sequence). The best way to do this is to use the abstract base classes from Python which you find in the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.abc.html) module. You have to implement only a minimum amount of methods and the module automatically implements the rest for you.

For your specific example, this would be something like this:

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

class MyList(MutableSequence):

    def __init__(self, iterable=()):
        self._list = list(iterable)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._list.__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self._list.__setitem__(key, item)
        # trigger change handler

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self._list.__delitem__(key)
        # trigger change handler

    def __len__(self):
        return self._list.__len__()

    def insert(self, index, item):
        self._list.insert(index, item)
        # trigger change handler
```

#### Performance

Some methods are slow in their default implementation. For example `__contains__` is defined in the [`Sequence` class](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/_collections_abc.py#l806) as follows:

```
def __contains__(self, value):
    for v in self:
        if v is value or v == value:
            return True
    return False
```

Depending on your class, you might be able to implement this faster. However, performance is often less important than writing code which is easy to understand. It can also make writing a class harder, because you're then responsible for implementing the methods correctly.

Comment: Thanks, the idea of subclassing from collections.abc is nice, because of the mixin methods. But what do you mean by your last sentence about assigning "the self._list's method to the MyList class".

Comment: @Dominik: I think he means that if you omit a method, it'll be provided by `MutableSequence`, but it probably will be less efficient than native list method written in C. For example, `clear` method provided by abc is roughly equivalent to `while self: del self[-1]`. If that happens to be bottleneck, you can just implement more efficient versions of those yourself in `MyList`.

Comment: For example, you could implement `clear` as `self._list.clear(); # trigger change handler`.

Comment: @Dominik: I meant that instead of adding your own `insert()` method, you could use the list's. Like this: `def __init__(self): self._list = list(); self.insert = self._list.insert`. In this case you would save one method lookup.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: that's not what I meant, but also an important point

Comment: @Georg: you could do that (`self.insert = self._list.insert`), but then you would be unable to have `# trigger change handler`.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: Good catch, I actually wanted to do this using a method where it's ok like `__getitem__`.

Comment: @Georg: I think that using that on `__getitem__` is also not possible, because magic methods have to be defined at class level, not instance level, in order to be invoked :)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: You're right. I should have known better!